# Netlify CMS Rebuild Config.yml Changes

Tags: netlify-cms

I am just getting started with Netlify CMS and I am confused how to update the CMS once my `admin/config.yml` changes

I cloned the default Hugo project and I modified some of the `config.yml` file fields for the home page and wired them up correctly in the index.html. The generated static file looks correct.

However, when I go to the CMS (`/admin`), I only see the old index.html content (in the CMS Preview section). So I renamed the `js` folder and copied only the `app.js` file into a fresh `js` folder. But that breaks things saying `cms.js` is missing. I added the old one but it did not pick up the `cms-preview-templates`.

I thought all of this will get generated from the `config.yml`.. Do I need to manually edit the JS files to setup the CMS? Or is it possible to regen all the files once `config.yml` and the associated html files change?

The help page on setting up your own site does not say much about editing the template.

**Update**
I see `cms.js` file has some content like this:

`import HomePreview from "./cms-preview-templates/home";
import PostPreview from "./cms-preview-templates/post";
import ProductsPreview from "./cms-preview-templates/products";
import ValuesPreview from "./cms-preview-templates/values";
import ContactPreview from "./cms-preview-templates/contact";`

and when I go check these files (`master` branch), they have the content from the original sample project and does not have the changes I made. What do I need to do to automatically update these template files as I make changes to my site (corresponding changes are in the `admin/config.yml` file)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making changes local in the project content will not be reflected in `NetlifyCMS` until you push those changes to the repository. The default `config.yml` setup does not include a local workflow because it does not have a local file system backend at this time.

Changes to the `admin/config.yml` will work locally, but expects the content data changes in the location of your backend configuration.

**Example:**

The following config will be looking for changes on `GitHub` in the `master` branch of `netlify/netlifycms-example` repository.

`admin/config.yml`

```
backend:
  name: github
  repo: netlify/netlifycms-example
  branch: master
```

**Update:** When you make changes to the `config.yml` and change the templates in your site generator, you will also need to make those changes inside the preview template code for the cms to display your data correctly in the previews.

Comment: thanks. Yes, I understand it has to be pushed to the repo and in fact I was directly running the CMS off Netlify.. When I noticed the old content there, I thought I need to somehow trigger an update to the JS files and was looking at my local source files. If I update the `admin/config.yml` file, do I need to do anything to tell the CMS the page templates have changed? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `netlify-cms-proxy-server` for local development.

Edit your config.yaml to add a `local_backend` field like so

```yaml
backend
  name: git-gateway

# important bits here
local_backend: true

...
```

Then, in the project's directory, start `netlify-cms-proxy-server`

```sh
npx netlify-cms-proxy-server
```

Start your local development server, and you should be good to go

```sh
# note: may be different depending on your project's configuration
hugo server -D
```

For more details, check out netlify-cms's  [docs](https://www.netlifycms.org/docs/beta-features/#working-with-a-local-git-repository) on working with a local git repo.